# Retrieving a web page including embedded objects

Tags: java, html

I'd like to fetch a web page including images, flash animations and other embedded objects. What's a straightforward way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

Writing a web-crawler in the java programming language.
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ThirdParty/WebCrawler/

Comment: Actually, it would be simpler to choose an existing one.  Hopefully someone will add an answer that lists some good alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Use an open source HTML Parser such as HTMLCleaner - http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers/htmlcleaner or CyberNekoHtml - http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers/nekohtml.

Once you have used a parser to create a representation of the DOM of the web page, you can then load/download images and other embedded objects that exist in the DOM by performing queries on the DOM and extracting relevant src attributes from the HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

try [web-harvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/)