# How we can Download a HTML Page using JAVA?

Tags: java, html, networking

How we can Download a HTML Page using JAVA??

Comment: Hi Binu, the following link should be of interest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664404/retrieving-a-web-page-including-embedded-objects

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download file by passing URL using java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302233/download-file-by-passing-url-using-java-code)

Comment: @McDowell,@James P : sorry, i dont know that there is some other  with same questions

Comment: Your question is seems to be little bit confusing whether you want to download html file from any server or you want to fetch html web page?

Comment: @Rupeshit : ya thats the word fetch...

Comment: @Binu: No worries. Sometimes a question can add something to what already exists. While you're browsing around, take a look at the related section of each question. Sometimes the links there are worth a read.

Comment: @James : Thks James, i will check the stuff when i do next time

Answer (score 10):

Here is the code:

```
public static String savePage(final String URL) throws IOException {
    String line = "", all = "";
    URL myUrl = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        myUrl = new URL(URL);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myUrl.openStream()));

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            all += line;
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    return all;
}
```

Now you can process one line after one other in the while loop.

Comment: can i add this stuff into my MySQL? how can i do that?

Comment: Of course you can. You can build some sting buffer from each line and put it in the database.

Comment: @akshayb - If so, why don't you add the new preferred way as a comment or modify the answer itself?

Answer (score 2):

If you have more requirements, like authentication, you can use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

Comment: No i just need to fetch the page and download it to my database, as for web index

Comment: Ok, then HttpClient is probably overkill

Comment: I mean that you will probably do fine with SINTER's solution. You can of course use HttpClient if you like.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), which compiles to java bytecode, you can fetch a page like this:

```
String text = new URL("http://google.com").text
```